# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python-3.x, list, attributes

i have a txt file and code like this :

------ this is the content inside data_user.txt ------

```
name  : aldo
email : alfo@gmail

name  : gume
email : gume@mail

name  : noname
email : noname@mail
```

------ this is my code -----

```
def modifytext2():
    file1 = open('data_user1.txt' , 'r') #read from txt file
    f = file1.readlines()
    g = [i.replace('@','---') for i in f]
    
    print(g)
    file1.close()

modifytext2()
```

when i run the code and the output will be, this successfull to change '@' become '---' :

```
['name  : aldo\n', 'email : alfo---gmail\n', '\n', 'name  : gume\n', 'email : gume---mail\n', '\n', 'name  : noname\n', 'email : noname---mail\n', '\n']
```

now i want to print the output line by line, similar with the txt file content, then i change my code become :

```
def modifytext2():
    file1 = open('data_user1.txt' , 'r') #read from txt file
    f = file1.readlines()
    g = [i.replace('@','---') for i in f]
    for x in g:
        g.write('\n')
    print(x)
    file1.close()

modifytext2()
```

after i change the code, it showing :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\NBUSER\Documents\ARTOFWAR\PITON\02-piton\copycontent.py", line 43, in <module>
    modifytext2()
  File "c:\Users\NBUSER\Documents\ARTOFWAR\PITON\02-piton\copycontent.py", line 38, in modifytext2      
    g.write('\n')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Comment: i think it should be like `file1.write(x)` instead of `f.write(x)`

Answer (score 0):

In your code `g` is a list and hence the error. Modify `g.write()` to `file1.write()` and you will be all set.
Here is the code you should try out:

```
def modifytext2():
    file1 = open('data_user1.txt' , 'r') #read from txt file
    f = file1.readlines()
    file1.close()
    g = [i.replace('@','---') for i in f]
    with open('data_user1.txt', 'w') as file1:
        for x in g:
            file1.write(x)

modifytext2()
```

Note: If you want to write back to same file use `data_user1.txt` in the second `open` call.

Output:

```
>> cat data_user2.txt
name  : aldo
email : alfo---gmail

name  : gume
email : gume---mail

name  : noname
email : noname---mail
```

Comment: sir, i actually change my question, and give more spesific case. would you like to help me solve this issue?

Comment: Edited the code, it should work now

Comment: when i run the code in your answer , it's make a new txt file with name ' data_user2.txt', i mean .. how we can do wihout storing it into new txt file.
is there another way to do that?

Comment: That's what I mentioned, use `data_user1.txt` in the second `open` call, anyways updated the code you can try out